# Symfony form - field modified

Tags: forms, symfony

Is there a way to check if field was modified in Symfony Form?
When form is created like this:

```
 $form = $this->createForm(ObjectType::class, $object);
```

Can I get a list of modified fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in way to get all of the changed/updated fields in a Doctrine 2 entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057558/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-get-all-of-the-changed-updated-fields-in-a-doctrine-2)

Comment: @Veve Same solution, but a little different problem. I weren't smart enough to think about doctrine.. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare object properties and show diff in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911067/compare-object-properties-and-show-diff-in-php)  :
If your entity is not mapped to doctrine: it's just having the difference between 2 php object.